# Python Error TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()

Tags: python, dynamic, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Hello I am writing and testing a recursive dynamic programmed knapsack (0-1) (the following code is the main file and the function) I keep getting the error (which is posted after the code)...I am really confused as to what the error is so any help will be much appreciated!

## MAIN FILE

```
import Knapsack_Test

size = 10
W = 2**size
knapsack = Knapsack_Test.Knapsack_Test()

for i in range(1, 10):
    knapsack.recursive_knapsack_test(size, W)
size = size + 100*i

W = 2**size
```

## FUNCTION CALLING (WHICH IS IN CLASS Knapsack_Test.py

```
def recursive_dynamic_knap(self, v, w, i, W):
    n = len(v) - 1
    if i == n:
        if W < w[n]:
            return 0
        else:
            return v
    elif W < w[i]:
        return self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W)

    return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])
```

## ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\Knapsack_Main.py", line 9, in <module>
    knapsack.recursive_knapsack_test(size, W)
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\Knapsack_Test.py", line 19, in recursive_knapsack_test
    self.knapsack.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, j, W)
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\KnapsackClass.py", line 22, in recursive_dynamic_knap
    return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\KnapsackClass.py", line 22, in recursive_dynamic_knap
    return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\KnapsackClass.py", line 22, in recursive_dynamic_knap
    return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\KnapsackClass.py", line 22, in recursive_dynamic_knap
    return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\KnapsackClass.py", line 22, in recursive_dynamic_knap
    return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\KnapsackClass.py", line 22, in recursive_dynamic_knap
    return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])
  File "\\minerfiles.mst.edu\dfs\users\asadmb\Desktop\Programming 3\KnapsackClass.py", line 22, in recursive_dynamic_knap
    return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()
```

Comment: Can you also post the function `knapsack.recursive_knapsack_test`?

Comment: PLEASE DISREGARD MY QUESTION I SOLVED IT!

Comment: It looks like `recursive_dynamic_knap` returns two types of values: `v`, which is a `list`, and `0`. Perhaps you meant to return `v[x]`? Comparisons between integers and lists are undefined.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your question.  There's no need to edit your post to say "disregard this" -- just 1) accept a posted answer that reflects your solution (marking the question as answered) or 2) if none of them do, then answer the question yourself with the solution you found and accept that.

Comment: @user1661211: If you have solved it, please post your solution as an answer to your question.

Comment: Andrew has provided the correct answer below =D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question owner says "PLEASE DISREGARD MY QUESTION I SOLVED IT!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that in `return max(self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1,W), self.recursive_dynamic_knap(v, w, i+1, W-w[i]) + v[i])` one of the calls to `recursive_dynamic_knap` is returning `v`, which is a list, and which makes no sense as an argument to `max()` because it is "unorderable" (can't sensibly be judged to be greater than or less than an `int`)

Comment: Yes that is the correct answers ...haha i already figured it out but thanks again!